# How to split a large mp3 into the different tracks (also in mp3)

Tags: software-recommendation, multimedia, mp3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I split a mp3 file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/27574/how-can-i-split-a-mp3-file)

I've got this huge mp3 file of the recording of a concert and I want to split each music into it's track so that when I burn into a cd audio it can have each track with a different song. What's the best apps for doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this: [How can I split a mp3 file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/27574/how-can-i-split-a-mp3-file/27575#27575) May be helpful for your case.

This will work on both wav, ogg, mp3 and other formats.

Good luck!